# If $\Omega$ is convex, then $K_{\Omega}$ is convex?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$K_{\Omega}=\{\lambda x|\lambda\ge0,x\in\Omega\}$$
Is it true that if $\Omega$ is convex, then $K_{\Omega}$ is also convex.

Let $\gamma\in(0,1)$ and $z,t\in K_{\Omega}$, so we have $z=\lambda x,t=\mu y$ such that $\lambda,\mu\ge0$ and $x,y\in\Omega$.

Now how $\gamma z+(1-\gamma)t=\gamma\lambda x+(1-\gamma)\mu y=\lambda\gamma x+\mu(1-\gamma)y$ can be in $K_{\Omega}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'll follow your notations, and I'll note  $A = \lambda \gamma + \mu(1- \gamma)$. If $\gamma = 0$ then obviously $\lambda\gamma x + \mu (1 - \gamma) y = \mu y \in K_\Omega$ . Otherwise, as $\lambda, \mu$ are positive, and $\gamma >0$, it is clear that $A>0$. Therefore,

$$\lambda\gamma x + \mu (1 - \gamma) y = A \times \left\lbrace \frac{\lambda \gamma}{A}x + \frac{\mu(1-\gamma)}{A}y \right\rbrace $$

The thing in the bracket is clearly a convex combination of elements $x$ and $y$ in $\Omega$ (note that $\lambda \gamma/A \in ]0,1[$), so the whole expression belongs to $K_{\Omega}$, which is convex.